# Delete CASCADE on field declared dynamically

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I have that constructor

```
/**
 * User constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->projectUser = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->skills = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->goals = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->technicalReferentOf = new ArrayCollection();

    parent::__construct();
}
```

And the `technicalReferentOf` variable is declared dynamically.

It's linked to that table which contains only foreign keys :

```
user_id |project_id |
--------|-----------|
46      |3          |
46      |13         |
69      |3          |
```

But when I want to delete a user I have a foreign key error, which I can't solve by a delete on cascade since there is no field.

What is the proper way to solve that problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you would like to remove all user's projects when particular `User` is deleted? I think you need to have a `CASCADE` on a DB layer in your join table...

Comment: No just the user :/ The question needs for informations ?

Comment: Alright, that makes things a bit clearer. As I said, you need to have a `CASCADE` on your join table. That `CASCADE` does not apply to the `project` table but only on a join table (that is, the key pair `(user_id, project_id)`). The keypair will be removed but the project will stay intact...

Comment: Ok I'm starting to understand. But where do I specify that ? Do I need to add a field on my User class ?

Comment: Nope, as far as your entities go, they should be fine. The `CASCADE` needs to be specified in a database (when you define your foreign keys)

Comment: Ok thanks ! Got it !! You can write it in an answer and I'll tick it :)

Comment: Cool, I've done that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `CASCADE` `ON DELETE` constraint on your joined table. I would encourage doing this for both `user_id` and `project_id` (assigned project can get deleted, right?).

Without knowing which DB vendor use, I cannot write the exact query to modify you table with but if you need help with that please provide an update in your question...

Hope this helps...